# udp socket stops receiving data

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am learning network programing in python and I'm trying to write a Toy vpn forked from android sdk https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/ToyVpn.

My Toy vpn is https://github.com/325862401/ToyVPN.

It's only for Linux.
My home network is behind NAT.

I can use this vpn to surf the internet after connect to remote sever.
But about half an hour or some time later the client `udp` socket stops receiving any data but the server can receive and send normally.
At this point I must terminate my client and run `ToyVpnClient` again.
It works normal for some time until it stop receiving again.

Please help me check the client logs.

```
>2013-08-24 11:42:38 INFO     receive data from the tunnel timeout`
```

you can see that when problem happens, the socket always sends, not receive.

`>` means `send`, `<` means `receive`

I want to know why the `udp` socket stops receiving data.

Is there any debug method to find the cause?

For now I've just used `logging` to debug my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying your client on the Internet, there is the whole universe of possible causes represented by all the Internet newtwork.

There's not a simple way of debugging here. Possible causes could be of course a software error but also some intermediate network configurations between you and the remote server.

You should capture the `udp` traffic using the good `wireshark` or the commandline `tcpdump` between you and the server and check if you're stopping sending packets or if the server is stopping receiving them. 
If you send packets but your server doesn't receive them ( `tcpdump` on the server ) then there is something on the network which decides to filter your packets. And if it's not on the server (firewall rules to rate limit packets for example or something like that) then there's nothing you can do to that without modifying the logic of your program. Like changing `UDP` port every X seconds or using a persistent `tcp` connection.

Answer (score 0):

A udp socket is not stable and may become null once a scanning or other event occupy your network interface for a while (especially true on Android). Using tcp avoids this problem. If you wants to maintain a stable udp, keep monitoring the status of your udp socket; if it becomes null or any unusual things happens, delete this socket and create a new one. Put this reactivating staff in a loop so that your udp socket is always alive.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.maybe the udp socket is not NULL.because it can send data to remote server and the server receive normally